# Can't update Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: updates

My update manager always failed the last few days. This what I get

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/rohityadav/vlmc/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Hi & welcome! Did you try to remove that ppa?

Answer (score 1):

Click on the Super (Windows) key and open software sources.

After that click on the other software tab

Find the repository that you posted (http://ppa.launchpad.net/rohityadav/vlmc/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/source/Sources) and remove that. You need to enter your root password to do that.

Again start the update manager and you will be fine.

Comment: @SamvelMartirosyan, if the answer was the right one for your problem, please *accept* it by clicking on the check mark.